# lucene.net + search only first page in the file 

Tags: wpf, lucene.net

i have requirement where i need to search only the first page of the file. Currently i am using **lucene.net** with **WPF**  for creating the indexes and searching the entire content of the file. i am able to return the results succefully. Now i need to search only the first page of the file i.e. **Each document will have a standard proforma which will have a specific location where keywords are assigned**. So can someone please guide me on this !!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use different fields when indexing different parts of the document and use the field names when you search.

See this [document](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/04/dissecting-lucene.net-storage-documents-and-fields.aspx) that explains fields in lucene

Comment: If I could expand a bit on what @cellik is saying - if you add a field that is specifically PageOne or some such, you can search only that field

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 1) how do i add fields and indexes for the FIRST PAGE and search can u pls post the code how to read the first page or any one particuler page number alone in the entire document 2) My data for searching the keywords are not standard it varies from each and every document!!